# swappable zram [hacking Linux kernel]

Tags: linux-kernel

On GNU/Linux I want to process some compressable data (something like Linux kernel sources) in RAM disk. Estimated maximum amount of data would be 2...3 times larger than RAM but expected to fit nicely if compressed. Ideally I'd like to use something like "tmpfs" which is not suitable as it is causing deadlocks when too much data provoke extensive swapping.
"zram" is an almost ideal solution but it is not swappable and therefore pinpoint too much RAM.
I wonder how it is possible to patch Linux kernel to make zram swappable, similar to tmpfs?

Can it be done by modifying GFP flags in "drivers/staging/zram/zram_drv.c"?

For instance there is a following line that I (rather naively) think can be modified to achieve the desiraable effect:

```
   zram->mem_pool = zs_create_pool("zram", GFP_NOIO | __GFP_HIGHMEM);
```

Any ideas please?